# MSBuild failing on a command I can run in the same developer console

Tags: windows, git, cmake, msbuild, chromium

I am using git inside of a vsproj file as generated from CMake.  It is producing a CUSTOMBUILD target that itsself is a command sequence that checks out a git repo from google chromium source.

```
CUSTOMBUILD : warning : subprocess '"git" "-c" "core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=512m" "clone" "--no-checkout" "--progress" "https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc.git" "build\_gclient_src_kpgzmk"' in build failed; will retry after a short nap... [webrtc-src.vcxproj]
```

Now if I run

```
git -c core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=512m clone --no-checkout --progress https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc.git build/_gclient_src_kpgzmk
```

it succeeds every single time, even if I give it a new folder as it does each time (with the stamp on the name)..

I am unable to get stdout from MSBuild on this issue it just says failed, trying after nap.  Honestly this is pretty head scratching because its the same command line console 'Developer Command Prompt' console environment on Windows 11 with VS.NET 2022 tools installed.  Again this is merely a shell command, git-scm installed and working.

[EDIT]
Went from 512m to 128m, thinking it could be a restriction on process memory invoked from MSBuild, but it errors in the same timeframe (around 11 seconds)
[/EDIT]

Comment: Can you add the code of the CUSTOMBUILD target from your CMakeLists.txt to the question?

Comment: Let me see what I can piece out of this thing, as its a rather large CMake script set

Comment: How is git invoked exactly? Just an idea, but thing is that git operations like clone write to stderr even when there aren't actual errors, and some tools interpret any stderr output as an error irregardless of exit code.